# Socket doesn't work with Android

Tags: android, sockets

I have a really simple server which I run as a Java application (It is the echoServer example). 
Also, I run the client as an android application but it doesn't even connect to the server... When I run debug it seems like it cannot find the java.net.socket library... It throws an exception "Source not found". How can I add the socket library in android? What else do you think should I try? I just want the client to connect to the server but it always says unfortunately socketclient has stopped.
Thank you so much!

The client code is:

```
public class SocketClient extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

        try {
            **socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);**
            Log.i("client", "connected!");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: I don't get a stack trace because it just crashes when it is in new socket(ip, port) line. In the debugging perspective it says "class file editor source not found. The JAR file C:\Users\pc\android-sdks\platforms\android-16\android.jar has no source attachment.  Also,  an error it gives is "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socketclient/com.example.socketclient.SocketClient}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` - this exception means exactly that - in Android you have to do all your networking in a separate thread.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I found some android socket examples on the internet where they do not use a different thread. However, I tried using a different activity to achieve the connection between client and server but I still get the same result.

Comment: Is the `ServerSocket` listening on port `4444`?

Comment: Hey guys I just created a new thread inside the oncreate method and finally it is connected! It doesn't crash at least. When I debug I still have the source not found thing. It's like this: http://manski.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/source-not-found.png  I don't know what android is looking for. Thank you all very much ! After so many hours client and server are connected... I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: In debug mode, the debugger will need the Android source code(packaged as a .jar or .zip file), so you can navigate around all java source code. You can find Android 2.3.3 source code [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/).